# iFrame loaded the page source of src attribute instead of rendering it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a bug that I'm unable to reproduce. An iframe that loaded the page source instead of rendering the page content. It works fine on the same machine with the same iframe src url with no changes to the environment (client side or server side).

Ideas? *See screenshots below.*

---

Here's what we're doing

1. We set `i1` and `i2`'s `src` attributes to "pageThatRedirects.html"
2. On iFrame load, the content loaded only displays the html for "pageThatRedirects.html"
3. When trying to reproduce this issue with the same iFrame src, everything works.

---

Is this a common issue? Did I run into a Chrome bug? Maybe it happens when the server's response time is too slow? Thoughts?

I tried to reproduce it by loading that same iFrame src in 10-15 iframes on the same page with a throttled connection -- in hopes of causing a performance/network issue, but I couldn't reproduce it. It was seen in Chrome 49 on OSX.

---

```
Page diagram (where i is an iFrame)
_____________
|     |     |
| i1  |  i2 |
|     |     |
|_____|_____|
```

[image: crazyiFrames]

Comment: 1. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "reproduce this issue with the same iFrame src". 2. Does "pageThatRedirects.html" open ok when not in an iFrame?

Comment: I took the url "http://whatever.com/pageThatRedirects.html" and attempted to reproduce it. It always works (resolves and renders content), even on the machine that had this issue, except for this one time. I'm new to frontend work, and iframes are a beast of their own -- i was hoping someone had seen something similar and could give me a place to start.

Comment: I think it is more likely that your server had a hiccup – and served the resource with the wrong `Content-Type` header (or none) “this one time.” (So not iframe-related at all.) If you have a rough idea what this one time actually was, then I’d check the server logs around that time for anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Yeah that makes the most sense to me. I can try and dig through them. Submit an answer... also if you have any ideas on how to restrict rendering within the iframes based on the presence of certain headers, I'd love to hear them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per CBroe's suggestion, I'm going to assume that the server wasn't setting the `Content-Type` header when serving `pageThatRedirects.html`